# How to use the plugin sfTCPDFPlugin?

Tags: plugins, symfony-1.4, tcpdf

I work with symfony 1.4, and I want to use the plugin sf sfTCPDFPlugin.
I followed step by step all the instructions, I read the question “How to generate PDF using sfTCPDFPlugin in symfony 1.4?” and answers, but when I try to generate a PDF file, I get the following error:
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".

In detail, I have done the following:

1. I installed PEAR - PHP Extension, and run OK.
2. I installed
   successfully the plugin sfTCPDFPlugin
3. I downloaded and installed
   the "TCPDF library"
4. $ symfony plugin:publish-assets
5. $ symfony cc
6. Copy the /plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin/config/pdf_configs.yml into the config folder of your application

Now I try to test the plugin, but when I want to run the function "test" that is included in the plugin, I get the following error:
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error":

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'TCPDF' not found in D:\proyectos\conflictosnew\plugins\sfTCPDFPlugin\lib\sfTCPDF.class.php on line 14

I use Wampsever under Windows XP

Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an error! The link contained in: "Download the TCPDF library" at: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin, is incorrect, because download fonts only, not the complete library
In the following link you can find the complete library TCPDF:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/